# Maximum Weight Increasing Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

In the [Longest Increasing Subsequence Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) if we change the length by weight i.e the length of each element A<sub>i</sub> is 1 if we change it to W<sub>i</sub> 
How can we do it in O(NlogN).

For Example
For an array of 8 Elements

```
Elements 1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4
Weights  10 20 30 40 15 15 15 50
```

The maximum weight is 110.

I found the LIS solution on wikipedia but I can't modify it to solve this problem.

Comment: Solve this on HackerRank with testcases - www.hackerrank.com/challenges/subsequence-weighting

Answer (score 4):

Still, we use `f[i]` denotes the max value we can get with a sequence end with `E[i]`.

So generally we have `for (int i = 1;i <= n;i++) f[i] = dp(i);` and initially `f[0] = 0;` and `E[0] = -INF;`

Now we shall calculate `f[i]` in `dp(i)` within `O(log(N))`.

in `dp(i)`, we shall find the max `f[j]` with `E[j] < E[i]` for all `0 <= j < i`. Here we can maintain a [`Segment Tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).

So `dp(i) = find_max(1,E[i]-1) + W[i]`(this takes `O(log)`), and for every f[i] already calculated, `update(E[i],f[i])`.

So the whole algorithm takes `(O(NlogN))`.

Tip: If `E[i]` varies in a very big range, it can be [`Discretization`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization)ed.

Comment: What is dp[i] ?
Can you please what will be stored in the Segment Tree?
Thanks.

Comment: @amahfouz dp(i) is just a function to calculate the the value of f[i]. In the segment tree, the index(or range) is the value of E, update value at single slot, query the max value in a range, typical segment tree.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure recursion implementation in swift:

```
// input is Array of (a,w), where a is element and w is weight

func lisw(input: [(Int, Int)], index:Int = 0, largestA:Int? = nil)->Int{
       guard index < input.count else { return 0 }

       let (a,w) = input[index]

       if a <= largestA {
          return lisw(input: input, index: index + 1, largestA: largestA)
       }

       let without_me = lisw(input: input, index: index + 1, largestA: largestA == nil ? a : largestA)
       let with_me = lisw(input: input, index: index + 1, largestA: a) + w

       return max(without_me,with_me)
}
```

Feel free to add memoization ;)